# Есть ли в джава аналог препроцессора как в с++

Tags: java

Есть ли в джава аналог препроцессора как в с++.(Есть ли анологи плюсовых define)

Comment: Сможете описать конкретную задачу? А обычно для таких целей в java используют static поля.

Comment: Спрашивал не для конкретной задачи

Comment: Наверное (внутри Makefile ?) можно использовать и стандартный препроцессор (со всеми include, макросами и т.п.). Как-то так: `gcc -E -xc YOUR-SOURCE-FILE | sed '/^#.*$/d' > YOUR-FILE-for-javac.java`

Comment: Вероятно, вас заинтересуют _макросы_. В Java их нет, но есть в Scala.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Коротко: нет, в `java` нет препроцессора.**

**Длиннее**: `java` является высокоуровневым языком (по крайней мере относительно `c++`), для которого препроцессор (ИМХО) был бы костылем.

Однако, в зависимости от целей, виртуальная машина `java` вполне может оптимизировать некоторые моменты на лету. Например:

```
public static final int someValue = 0;
```

В `java` будет работать во многих случаях так же, как и `#define someValue 0` в `c++`. Если вам действительно нужен препроцессор, то можете воспользоваться чем-то вроде [этого](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor).

Не знаю, для чего вам понадобился препроцессор, но может быть вы хотите генерировать различные исходники в зависимости от каких-то факторов? (Мне как-то для проекта понадобились различные версии векторов - `Vec3f (float)` `Vec3d (double)` и так далее. Мне было лень дублировать исходники для каждого примитивного типа, и я написал класс-шаблон для [Apache Velocity](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Apache_Velocity), который потом при сборке `gradle`-ом прогонял через, в общем-то, сам `velocity`, и после сборки у меня было несколько идентичных классов для разных типов переменных).

Поэтому можете использовать `velocity`, если вам нужно генерировать что-то по шаблону.

Как-то так.

Answer (score 2):

В Java нет (встроенного в сам язык) препроцессора, но существуют неплохие решения:

- [java-comment-preprocessor](https://github.com/raydac/java-comment-preprocessor) - простое и функциональное решение, работает как Maven/Gradle-плагин;
- [Manifold](https://github.com/manifold-systems/manifold) - в состав Manifold входит препроцессор. Решение менее универсальное так как требует поддержку со стороны IDE (необходим плагин для IDEA).

Лично я периодически пользуюсь java-comment-preprocessor.